# jQuery's offset() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know jQuery does most when it comes to cross-browser issues. I just wanted to know if `offset()` method of jQuery serves the purpose of cross-browser compatibility, I mean `top`, `left`, etc properties that can be derived from it?

Basically once I apply `top`, `left`, etc properties (which are derived from `offset()` function) to an element, I need to make sure that the element appears at the specified location across all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless otherwise noted in the documentation, all jQuery methods will work in every [supported browser](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility).

You can also search the [bug tracker](http://dev.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you're doing doesn't involve taking the element out of flow and the document re-flowing, it **should behave the same in all browsers**.  If you cause a re-flow, you need to reposition in some edge cases.